# InternalError on multipart upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Recently my code is facing intermittent issues with a bucket in S3 that is basically downloading, parsing and reuploading files, I'm using python and boto (not boto3) to do the S3 actions my version is boto 2.36.0 Do you have any idea why sometimes S3 gives that kind of errors.

Based on their documentation
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadComplete.htmlç](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadComplete.html%C3%A7)

Sample Response with Error Specified in Body
The following response indicates that an error occurred after the HTTP response header was sent. Note that while the HTTP status code is 200 OK, the request actually failed as described in the Error element.

But still is not really a good example of what's going on and why it happens sometimes

I've tried some manual uploads to my bucket using the same version but I haven't noticed anything while doing it manually

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>InternalError</Code>
<Message>We encountered an internal error. Please try again.</Message>
<RequestId>A127747D40AB1AC3</RequestId>
<HostId>Clz3f+rO2K1KfD0ZwSkpa9WnPvUh/mngdi99eDiSbdR0uzOP5a7RcYUem6ILYbtQdIJ02aUw2M4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: That should not be happening.  Is it possible that you are actually trying to complete the same multipart upload more than once?

Comment: Well, it could be, I try to use boto to do the retry logic, but I was thinking that if the multipart upload fails due to network latency or long running process are there might be that S3 is returning before I finish to upload. Just a thought based on this issue [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/501#issuecomment-171491402)

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this?